# Is it possible to do Algebraic Operations in Solr Result set?

Tags: solr

Currently I am firing 3 Solr queries and doing operations in my servlet to achieve my requirement. My requirement is finding words that belong to non special category.

Special category words will have entries in special documents as well as normal documents, there will be two special categories. So I need to extract all the documents and remove the special categories from that. Currently I am doing that in servlet using Hash Maps.

Is it possible to do that in a Solr query without writing any handlers?

I wanted to achieve something like query1 - (query2 U query3)

Comment: If you post what your actual 3 queries are, someone maybe able to answer this.

Comment: Do you want to perform [Set operations - like in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29)?

Comment: @cheffe yes absolutely that is what i wanted to do in solr...

Comment: Am I missing something or this is the same as `query1 NOT (query2 OR query3)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter queries to exclude results of other queries from the original query. In Solr you can negate a query result using `-`. This will not cover all possible Set Operations, but it should suffice for your needs.

To give an example, assumed you query for T-Shirts of a certain company

```
q=company:hilfiger
```

Now you want to exclude those Shirts which are red or green. To do that you negate each query with a `-` and you would add a separate `fq` parameter for each constraint.

```
fq=-color:red&fq=-color:green
```

Putting all that together you would query for

```
`q=company:hilfiger&fq=-color:red&fq=-color:green
```

References about filter queries

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq%28FilterQuery%29Parameter

Comment: But i don't know what are the things i have to exclude. The thing is i may in need of excluding 1000 words produced by query2, 1000 words produced by query3 from 3000 words produced by query1

Comment: Then explain your scenario better, give us your schema, explain which queries you use and which result you want to achieve ...

Comment: @KarthikSurianarayanan The result of a solr query is a set of documents, not words: what do you mean by "excluding 1000 words produced by query2"?

Comment: @Zac excluding 1000 documents by query2, 1000 documents by query3 from 3000 documents producedd by query1. Note: have to do this operation based on the field _word it will be there in all the documents returned by query 1,2,3